# writing output to directory where exe is opened from

Tags: c#

I have a form `exe`. now on button click i want it to save a file to where it has been opened from, e.g. if i give this `exe` to you and you copy it to  c drive folder name "la-la" then it save file to c drive folder name la-la.

At the moment I am trying this which works but I don't want it to provide path to directory anymore,

```
 myVar.Save(@"C:\lala\test.xml");
```

What can I use using .Net 2.0.

Comment: `Application.StartupPath`

Comment: Bear in mind the exe could be run from c:\ but on recent windows version write permission would be denied in a non elevated context.

Comment: What is the type of `myVar` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myVar.Save(@"test.xml");
```

This should write `test.xml` to the directory your exe runs from.

Note that in case of writing to `c:\` root folder might require elevated administrator permissions.

You didn't specify the type of myVar, but this might be helpful:

```
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        File.WriteAllText("HelloWorld", "test.txt");
    }
}
```

This creates `test.txt` file with `HelloWorld` content, the file is saved in the executable
directory.

Comment: To output the concurrent results to log file, it's more appropriate to call File.AppendAllText, not File.WriteAllText. See msdn here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.io.file

Comment: @Itachi, you are right, he didn't mention the use of that `.xml` file.
This example is to meant to show the way to save a file to the execution directory.
No word about appending in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at using [AppDomain.BaseDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)

> Gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for
>   assemblies.

You also need to look at using [Path.Combine Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx)

> Combines two strings into a path.